backup of db after reboot or maintenance with scheduling using crontab
Implemented a script in bash that backups a postgres db and added in my root user crontab:
$ sudo crontab -e
0 3,14 * * * /usr/local/bin/backup.sh 10 >> /mnt/backups/backup.log

so it would run daily at 3am and 2pm (at 14 hours) and logs to backup.log to keep a track if running as expected and so on.
now my question is that follows the below requirement? I think it does since using the crontab in sudo so it shouldn't be lost in a reboot but not a expert should there be any extra step that should be done (this will be using containers).

In case of a restart or maintenance of a Linux server the process of
backup should be able to execute in the time slot for backup without
additional intervention.


Do ditch crontab and use /etc/crontab. Has an extra option to include a user to run a command for.


since using the crontab in sudo so it shouldn't be lost in a reboot

It will work after a reboot so no problem there.

In case of a restart or maintenance of a Linux server the process of backup should be able to execute in the time slot for backup without additional intervention.

That script will start if the system is up and running. If it is off it will not.
